# ERROR: Module mod_vhost_alias does not exist

Tags: apache, apache2, apache-modules

I am trying to enable mod_vhost_alias in apache.
I did some Googling and found a command

```
sudo a2enmod mod_vhost_alias
```

I tried that but then I get this

```
ERROR: Module mod_vhost_alias does not exist!
```

How do I make mod_vhost_alias exist?

Download it somewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just remove `mod` prefix. Most of apache modules enabled/disabled without `mod` prefix.

Right command:

```
sudo a2enmod vhost_alias
```

Comment: Thank you! I just realized that too :)

Answer (score 4):

I had the name wrong.
All I had to do was this:

```
sudo a2enmod vhost_alias
```

And it worked.
By the way, here is what I added to the default `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` file

```
# DocumentRoot /var/www
VirtualDocumentRoot /home/drew/sites/%0
ServerAlias *
```